# Denied issues remain even selinux policies are created

Tags: selinux, android-7.1-nougat, libselinux

The selinux mechanism is deployed on android 7.1, so I must fix selinux denied issues. Now there are only two denied issues remained, but I have write these two accesses in selinux policies in policy file. That are denied issues' log below:

```
avc: denied { write } for pid=3868 comm="droid.launcher3" name="galcore" dev="tmpfs" ino=101 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mrvlgpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0

avc: denied { write } for pid=3830 comm="ndroid.systemui" name="galcore" dev="tmpfs" ino=101 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mrvlgpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
```

And two respective policies writen in policies files like below:

```
allow priv_app mrvlgpu_device:chr_file create_file_perms;
allow platform_app mrvlgpu_device:chr_file create_file_perms;
```

Apparently, I have enabled related accesses, but denied errors are still remained. I don't know how to fix these denied issues?